# Pandas Dataframe: How to separate my python dictionary values where there is a comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8bn.png)I currently have a python dictionary with a stock ticker as a key, and various fundamentals as the values.

ex) {'stock1': ['P/E Ratio, EPS, Dividend Yield], 'stock2: ['P/E Ratio, EPS, Dividend Yield]}

[image]

When I write my pandas dataframe to an xlsx file it reads the dictionary values as 1 long string. This string is being stored in a single row and I want each comma separated value to be in its own row.

Any ideas how to break up the current string into separated values?? Thanks!

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Did you miss the closing quotes in P/E Ratio and stock2 or is your data itself like that ?

Comment: Hyperlinked image of my code. Thanks

Comment: follow SO guidelines.  Images are not at all helpful for getting answers